# Passing parameters through sharepoint sitepage to web part

Tags: sharepoint, parameters, web-parts

So I'm building sharepoint pages that are consisted of web parts. I need to send parameter to a page, and that send it further to these web parts, and I have no idea how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOTB way:

You can use query string filter web part to capture the query string values and pass it to the web parts.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-query-string-url-filter-web-part-to-another-web-part-HA010250999.aspx

Custom WebParts:

You can use the following code snippet to capture the query string.

```
Request.QueryString["param"]
```

Comment: I'm using first way, and after I add Query String (URL) Filter and hover over "Edit/Connections/Send Filter Values To" I get "The connection type "send filter values to" is not compatible with any other web parts on the page". I don't know how to connect these web parts.

Comment: What are the other web parts ?

Comment: You need to make it a consumer web part, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460810(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I did it! Followed this article: http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=118. Thanks for your help Madhur!

Comment: @FraneNovakovic, can you share how you achieved it? The blog you mentioned now is locked by password.