# SharePoint 2013: Consuming query (url) filter in custom webparts

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am building webparts and self hosted apps for sharepoint 2013, I want to consume the Query String filters that the user sets up, the process should be as simple as specified [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-query-string-url-filter-web-part-to-another-web-part-HA010250999.aspx) on this microsft site.

Unfortunately I dont get the option to send values to 'my web part' but I do for other stock webparts that come with sharepoint. Which leads me to believe I need to implement IFilter or equivelent in my webpart, I have found information into [IFilterConsumer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.communication.ifilterconsumer.aspx) interface and [IFilterProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.communication.ifilterprovider.aspx) interface on msdn which seems to be exactly what I need, however the documentation has one snag:

NOTE: This API is now obsolete.

So My question is, what is Microsofts new intended way of doing this with Sharepoint 2013.

Ultimately I need to read query variables in the HostWeb request inside my AppWeb code.

Edit: Apparently IWebPartParameters is the new interface for this.... trying to implement now.

I have also tried whats suggested here:
[Passing parameters through sharepoint sitepage to web part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482143/passing-parameters-through-sharepoint-sitepage-to-web-part) Still not working, at the moment I have implemented IWebPartParameters, IWebPart, IWebPartRow and none of my functions that implement these interfaces are being called. I must be missing something in the manifest or features file maybe?

Thanks in advance

Crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer to this question is simple, firstly you can only do this in a dev environment with sharepoint installed, as you need access to the sharepoint.dll.

Then this thread answers the question http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=19791, with the following code solution which is here http://www.markitup.com/BookCodeSamples/TestingWebPartConnections.zip